# Pinescript Code Error "Trading View" Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ')

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

```
label.new(
    bar_index, na,
    text = "VWAP: " + tostring(vwap) + "\nRSI: " + tostring(rsi) + "\nOBV: " + tostring(obv) + "\nOBV Smooth: " + tostring(smoothingLine) +
    "\n\nCurrent Values:\nClose: " + tostring(close) + "\nVolume: " + tostring(volume),
    yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = color.new(color.white, 0), style = label.style_labeldown
)
```

I'm getting the error as "Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ')'".

Can you anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write statements on a new line, then the continuation of the statement must begin with one or several (different from multiple of 4) spaces.

See [line wrapping](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html#line-wrapping).

```
label.new(
     bar_index, na,
     text = "VWAP: " + tostring(vwap) + "\nRSI: " + tostring(rsi) + "\nOBV: " + tostring(obv) + "\nOBV Smooth: " + tostring(smoothingLine) +
     "\n\nCurrent Values:\nClose: " + tostring(close) + "\nVolume: " + tostring(volume),
     yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = color.new(color.white, 0), style = label.style_labeldown)
```